# Should I use "this" or "he" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> "Hey," he said pointing to my friend, "who is—hey, isn't **this** Scott 'Sheep' McJones?"
>
> "Hey," he said pointing to my friend, "who is—hey, isn't **he** Scott 'Sheep' McJones?"

Not sure why I'm confused. Seems like very grammar, ha.

Comment: In what context do you imagine yourself needing to produce this sentence?

Comment: @δοῦλος OK, I updated.

Comment: Actually, at that point, the speaker would say "who is...hey, aren't *you* Scott 'Sheep' McJones!?"

Comment: @TRomano: Not necessarily.  If the speaker is speaking to the narrator, and not to Scott McJones, it would make more sense to say "this" or "that" or "he".  For all we know, the speaker could be pointing at a picture of the friend.

Comment: True enough. That scenario would be even more likely if he had said "pointing to *a picture* of my friend".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way--or some other way--could be said and make sense, all depending on the context for the purpose of the utterance, the personality of the person speaking, and the relationship of that person with both other people,

Sometimes, the use of the third-person (he, she) to refer to someone in their presence can be obnoxious or demeaning.

> "Hey," Joe said pointing to my friend, "who is—hey, isn't [this | he] Scott 'Sheep' McJones?"

Note that Scott's nickname was 'Sheep' which is derogatory.  Let's say Joe called Scott 'Sheep' 10 years ago in high school. So Joe is a stereotypical jerk. It would make sense to write about Joe saying this since he's the obnoxious type, and he's still holding onto his own self esteem by thinking of others as "losers" and putting them down.  The meaning may depend on various contexts:

- **Distance.**  Is Scott within earshot of Joe?
- **Eye Contact.**  Is Joe looking at Scott as he is talking?  Is Scott looking at Joe?  Are their eyes locked together in a staring contest?
- **State of mind.**  Is Joe drunk?
- **Environment.** Are they in a bar?  Is Scott with his girlfriend/wife/fiance? Are they in a group?  Are they alone on an empty street at night? Are they in a business meeting?
- **History.** Did Joe and Scott have some personal history in high school?  Did Joe beat up Scott?  Or did they fight back and forth in their own way, each having various personal victories over they other?

Any way of saying your sentence can make sense given various contexts.

Answer (score 1):

*This* by itself sort of implies either:

- you didn't know if Scott 'Sheep' McJones was a person or not.
- or you're talking to someone on the phone and trying to confirm who a voice is.

It would sound better if:

> "Hey," he said pointing to my friend, "who is—hey, isn't this *the* Scott 'Sheep' McJones?"

Answer (score 1):

People rarely speak with impeccable grammar. Either version would sound like something a native speaker would say. The "isn't this Scott McJones?" construction is really just eliding the word "person" -- "isn't this [person] Scott McJones?"

It's true that the more polite thing to do, if all people are present, would be to say "Hey, aren't you Scott McJones?" But people aren't always polite; if writing fiction, it will depend on the character speaking whether they'd address the OMG SCOTT MCJONES! or their friend.